# Write autohotkey script to go through a text file and add in text after certain other text

Tags: autohotkey

I have to complete a very tedious task at work that involves opening up code, copying it to notepad, adding text after other specific text, cut and pasting some other test to another line and then saving the file.  I've already figured out how to add the copying process to a hotkey, but I think I need some help to write the code that traverses through the text and adds specific alphanumeric codes.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
F12::
Send ^a 
Send ^c
Run Notepad
Sleep 500
Send ^v
/*
text traversing/modifying code goes here
*/
return
```

Comment: Did you see that I answered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at `fileopen`, `fileread` and `fileappend` in the docs.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm

I just [posted an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903498/determine-if-string-exists-in-file/17904896#17904896) of how to read a file into a variable and parse it. You could easily add `fileappend` into the loop.

Looks like you've already figured out the hotkey.

`fileappend` will write a line to the end of a text file - like a log would work.  It doesn't overwrite the file.  Actually, if you use `fileappend`, you don't need to `send ^v` - which is actually more reliable because you don't have to fiddle with the GUI of any window.  In fact, you don't need to open the file in notepad at all!  Just read the file into a variable, parse it, do to the text (in the variable) whatever you want, and write it back to file.