# Getting a line from file - AutoHotkey

Tags: search, autohotkey

I'm trying to make an AHK script, that'll search through given file and get a line from it as a variable.
File looks like this:

```
word - another word
word1 - another word1
```

Let's say that "word" is %x%

I want the script to search for %x%, get the whole line with it and split the line to %x% and %y%, where %y% is "another word".
Unfortunately, code from [Determine if string exists in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903498/determine-if-string-exists-in-file) wasn't working for me as I wanted to, so I hope I made things here clear enough to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with a [regex](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm).

Let's say `fCnt` contains the contents of the file.

```
If RegExMatch(fCnt, "Om)^\Q" x "\E - (.+)$", m)
    MsgBox % "The value of y is: " m.1
```